# How to repeat once at a time in a loop or IF statement in C language?

Tags: c++, c

I am doing an assignment in C language programming concerning either a WHILE loop, a FOR loop or an IF statement. I have tried all kinds of ways to do it, but failed. I need someone to help me solve this problem.
I want to repeat a certain expression until I get a number which fulfills either one of my top two conditions.
The code goes like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int function;

    printf("Please choose a function:\n>>");
    scanf("%d",&function);
    printf("\n");
    if(function==1)
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("Nice");
    }
    else if(function==2)
    {
        printf("You chose to exit.\n\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else if(function>2)
    {
        printf("Error! Please try again.\n\n");
    }
    else;
    return 0;
}
```

The part that I want to repeat is this until I get either 1 or 2 as my number.

```
else if(function>2)
    {
        printf("Error! Please try again.\n\n");
    }
```

Anybody has a way of solving this? It doesn't matter if I have to change this IF statement into a FOR loop or WHILE loop, as long as the results come out as what I mentioned above.

Comment: You should also consider -1, and the return value of scanf.

Comment: Surely the part that you _actually_ want to repeat is the call to `scanf` otherwise the value of `function` will never change?

Comment: When you start out try the simplest problem first. Try to write a program that accepts a quit option but nothing else. It helps if you think about smaller tasks first.

Comment: I've done that actually, but now I'm facing problems in adding stuff inside my sub-programs, that's where I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're allowed more than one of `while`/`for`/`if`, how about a mixture of `do` ... `while` and `if`

```
int function;
do {
    while (scanf("Please choose a function:\n>>%d", &function) != 1)
        ;
    printf("\n");
    if(function==1) {
        system("cls");
        printf("Nice");
    }
    else if(function>2) {
        printf("Error! Please try again.\n\n");
    }
} while (function != 2);
printf("You chose to exit.\n\n");
return 0;
```

Comment: This code is quite complicated. I only understand the part do{...}while(); but I don't understand the part below it and the part else if(function>2). What would happen if I press the number 2? Will it end the program? What would happen if I press a number bigger than 2? Will there be a loop going on, one at a time?

Comment: If you enter 1, the program will print "Nice" then exit.  If you enter 2, the do while loop will exit.  If you enter a number larger than 2, the program will print "Error..." then ask for another number.  The short `while` loop checks that the user entered a single number and asks the question again if they entered anything wrong.

Comment: This is the best answer I've got so far, and complicated it might seem, it DID solve my problem. Thank you for the code :)

Answer (score 3):

use this may help you.

```
for(i=1;i<10;i++)
{
printf("Please choose a function:\n>>");
scanf("%d",&function);
printf("\n");
if(function==1)
{
    system("cls");
    printf("Nice");
}
else if(function==2)
{
    printf("You chose to exit.\n\n");
    return 0;
}
else if(function>2)
{
    printf("Error! Please try again.\n\n");
}
}
```

you can put any number depanding upon your requirment..I have used 10 in for loop. You can use as per your requirment

Comment: I guess he wants an infinite loop, since he explicitly used `while(1)` and has an exit strategy...

Comment: @Saccha Where has he used while(1)??

Comment: hmm... I guess I mixed something up ... with one of the anwesers. Sorry... you're right!! My bad!

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in a loop

```
while(1)
{
    printf("Please choose a function:\n>>");
    scanf("%d",&function);
    printf("\n");
    if(function==1)
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("Nice");
        break;
    }
    else if(function==2)
    {
        printf("You chose to exit.\n\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else if(function>2)
    {
        printf("Error! Please try again.\n\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you want a 'break;' after the 'printf("Nice");' line.

Comment: Or use `while (function > 2)` instead of `while (1)`

Comment: The requirement is an infinite loop, I think as long as 2 is not chosen

Comment: Thanks uba, but actually I'm planning to add another function inside the part if(function==1), which does not repeat the whole main function. The part else if(function>2) should be part of my sub functions, and that is the only part I want to repeat, mind to give me some help there?

Comment: edited. Will work as required now..

Comment: The printf("Please choose a function") keeps repeating itself, can I make that disappear and only repeat the printf("Error") instead?

Comment: move it outside the loop (before the while statement). Then it will be printed only once.

Comment: It's not working, I get infinite printf("Error") loops if I move printf("Please choose") outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with a while loop and a switch statement.

Something like so (not sure if it complies, just to show you what I mean):

```
function = 0;
do
{
    printf("Please choose a function:\n>>");
    scanf("%d", &function);
    switch(function)
    {
        case 1:
            /* do your stuff */
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Error! Please try again.\n\n");
            break;
    }
} while(function != 2)
```

Comment: Do I need to put break after the expression printf("Error") if I want it to loop back until I get a number 1 or 2?

Comment: I'm not sure if you need a `break`on the very last case. I simply put it at every end, so if I append another case, even just for testing, , I don't get strange results because it is missing.

Answer (score 0):

use can use a do while loop

```
int main()

int function;
do {
  printf("Please choose a function:\n>>");
  scanf("%d",&function);
  printf("\n");
  if(function==1) {
      system("cls");
      printf("Nice");
  }
  else if(function==2)  {
      printf("You chose to exit.\n\n");
      return 0;
  }
  else  {
      printf("Error! Please try again.\n\n");
  }
} while (function > 2)
return 0;
```

}

Comment: `while(function != 2)` perhaps? But on the other hand, the `function == 2` is covered by the `return 0` in the loop, so a `for(;;)` at the beginning would be better in this particular case...

Comment: I want the printf("Error") to go on once at a time until I either hit a number 2 or number 1, instead of ending the program, mind to twitch your code a little for me to understand?